# HTML Drop-down list options from array

Tags: html

It's there any possibility to make an HTML drop-down list with options from array, or any another collection.

Comment: Yes.  It is possible to generate HTML from data.

Comment: Have you tried www.google.com?

Comment: We need more specifics for this question. Is this a JavaScript array, or a server side programming array? An example of the data would be a good addition as well.

Comment: Yes, it's stupid question. But your answers gave me an understanding. I will use JSTL forEach loop to generate select options. Thanks) And sorry again)

Comment: `<select>
  <c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
    <option><c:out value="${item}"/></option>
  </c:forEach>
</select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<select>` and `<option>`s:

```
<select id="select"></select>
```

You can populate this with `<option>`s from JS (this solution uses jQuery for simplicity):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$(arr).each(function(i, v) {
   $("#select").append("<option value='" + i + "'>" + v + "</option>");
});
```

Comment: I don't see a `jQuery` tag on this question...

Comment: @AndrewMairose  don't see a `JavaScript` tag on this question for your answer either,,, =)

Comment: Haha, touche my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you would do it:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('your-select');
var array = ['opt1', 'opt2', 'opt3'];

for (var i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = i;
  opt.innerHTML = array[i];
  select.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<select id="your-select"></select>
```